# Since update of Firefox v37 internet access is slow

Tags: firefox, internet

Before the auto update to Firefox v37 occurred Firefox worked fine on my Ubuntu 14.04 system (ethernet connected to  20Gbps internet up 4Gbps down).

My system is 8 core, 32GB ram, ubuntu 14.04 w/latest updates.

***After auto update to Firefox v37***, Firefox now sometime times-out, or experiences very long delays (30+ seconds or more) in connecting to common WWW sites like gmail.com, google.com.

*While that Firefox delay is occurring, pings to the very same site work fine and the round trip time is usually 32-40msec.*

Also, if I start Chrome and Firefox at the same time and point both of them to the same website (gmail.com, google.com etc)... *Chrome will connect instantly while Firefox will show it's spinner and experience the long delays*.

Note that Firefox v37 doesn't do this every time but maybe 1/2 - 2/3rds of the time.

Both Chrome & Firefox are using HTTPS.

Anyone else seeing this on their systems or can point me to a Bug report?   I searched Launchpad bugs but didn't see anything jump out as a bug report related to this kind of problem.

Comment: [firefox bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox) - looks like you are not alone.

Comment: Are there any Plugins installed? What about private mode, or a new profile?

Comment: You can check network speed via `www.speedtest.net`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Firefox profile to eliminate your preferences or Add Ons as being the slow culprit.  If it's still slow, something's wrong with your Firefox installation.

Reinstall half of your Add Ons to see if one or more of them is slow.  Use a binary search to determine which Add On it might be.  Warning: More than one Add On might be a problem.  Then you'll have to check each one individually.

If you use Firefox sync, you might try your profile on a new/different installation of Firefox (perhaps in a VirtualBox or a VMware Player guest).

Answer (score 1):

My firefox takes almost a minute to load a page on every install (since Ubuntu 13.10 if I remember correctly). The only way to fix it is go to `about:config` (you write it where you write the pages url) and search for `ipv6`. Then change `network.dns.disableIPv6` to `true` (maybe my router doesn't support IPv6 and causes firefox to search for it but it isn't needed yet so you won't have any problem and I think older versions had IPv6 disabled by default). After this, pages load within 1 sec.